# How do I include in my Eclipse project, native Android code located in a directory external to my project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have an android test project that includes JNI code from elsewhere in my repository. For instance, my Android.mk file resembles the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Android.mk
```

I have opened my project in eclipse, enabled native support, and switched to the Android Native perspective. The project builds and runs correctly.

My problem is that my native c++ code is not present in the eclipse workspace. I can't see it under the jni folder or under any of the project's sub folders. My question is, how do I include the native code in my workspace so that I can edit it, and set breakpoints (via Sequoyah)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a linked folder to your eclipse project, see http://www.russellbeattie.com/blog/1002305